# Automatic Trigger not executing all the time,code was not executing some time

Tags: azure-functions

I am working with azure function app. which was working fine in my local.After deployment it was not triggering as expected some time it was not at all executing only few times it is. can anybody suggest me how can we run this with out missing the execution.

Comment: Which Trigger you are using for the Azure  function app ?

Comment: Time Trigger part of logic not executing properly not all the time for some time only

Comment: What's your cron expression and did you set the always on?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a sync triggers issue but not sure at this time. Can you try clicking the refresh button for your function in the portal? I'm not sure what the issue could be yet, but I want to see if that fixes it.

[image]

**The most common issue for causing Azure Functions not to trigger is that some deployment or IDEs do not trigger a synchronization on a consumption plan with the central listener**.

This is explained in this GitHub thread.
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/210

Comment: Some times it was executing my logic , some times not

Comment: If i Run Manually in portal it was working fine,facing the issue when it was triggering automatically